# All possible combination - Runtime error 6 on VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I have this code where the purpose is to get all the possible combinations depending on the filters selected by the user. The columns from L to P are where the selected filters are ( depending on the filter they can go from 1 to 12), and the range V7 to Z7 is where I want to display the combinations.

On other similar questions with the same error the main reason is the variable type "long", but i'm already using it as they suggested.

```
    Columns("V:Z").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Dim c1() As Variant
    Dim c2() As Variant
    Dim c3() As Variant
    Dim c4() As Variant
    Dim c5() As Variant
    Dim out() As Variant
    Dim l As Long, m As Long, n As Long, o As Long, p As Long, q As Long


    Dim col1 As Range
    Dim col2 As Range
    Dim col3 As Range
    Dim col4 As Range
    Dim col5 As Range
    Dim out1 As Range


    Set col1 = Range("L7", Range("L7").End(xlDown))
    Set col2 = Range("M7", Range("M7").End(xlDown))
    Set col3 = Range("N7", Range("N7").End(xlDown))
    Set col4 = Range("O7", Range("O7").End(xlDown))
    Set col5 = Range("P7", Range("P7").End(xlDown))

    c1 = col1
    c2 = col2
    c3 = col3
    c4 = col4
    c5 = col5

    'Here is where I get the error
    Set out1 = Range("V7", Range("Z7").Offset(UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5)))
    out = out1

    l = 1
    m = 1
    n = 1
    o = 1
    p = 1
    q = 1

    Do While l <= UBound(c1)
        Do While m <= UBound(c2)
            Do While n <= UBound(c3)
                Do While o <= UBound(c4)
                    Do While p <= UBound(c5)
                        out(q, 1) = c1(l, 1)
                        out(q, 2) = c2(m, 1)
                        out(q, 3) = c3(n, 1)
                        out(q, 4) = c4(o, 1)
                        out(q, 5) = c5(p, 1)
                        q = q + 1
                        p = p + 1
                    Loop
                    p = 1
                    o = o + 1
                Loop
                o = 1
                n = n + 1
            Loop
            n = 1
            m = m + 1
        Loop
        m = 1
        l = l + 1
    Loop

    out1.Value = out
```

Comment: I bet `UBound(c1) * UBound(c2) * UBound(c3) * UBound(c4) * UBound(c5)` is greater than 1048569.

Comment: I calculate the max of combinations that could exist and the total is 608304. Could it be the way I wrote the code that is giving a greater number than that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after checking line by line of the code. Gonna leave it here in case someone need it in the future.
Basically if there was only one value selected as filter ( columns L to P) than the Ranges

```
     Set col1 = Range("L6", Range("L6").End(xlDown))
     Set col2 = Range("M6", Range("M6").End(xlDown))
     Set col3 = Range("N6", Range("N6").End(xlDown))
     Set col4 = Range("O6", Range("O6").End(xlDown))
     Set col5 = Range("P6", Range("P6").End(xlDown))
```

would be 1048569. So I just had to make sure there were at least 2 values.

Comment: This is why it is safer to use XlUp

Comment: That didn't occur to me at the moment but yes it works if you use Xlup. Thanks Scott.